# Как просмотреть текстовые файлы в каталоге и во всех его подкаталогах (скрипты BASH)

Tags: bash, shell

Как просмотреть текстовые файлы в каталоге и во всех его подкаталогах, а также подкаталогах каталогов(и тд, пока все папки не закончатся).

Comment: 1. что именно вы подразумеваете под «текстовыми файлами»? 2. что именно вы подразумеваете под словом «просмотреть»? 3. как вы представляете **одновременный** «просмотр» нескольких файлов?

Comment: под просмотром я имею ввиду самый обычный "cat".

Comment: Мне нужно просто все файлы командой cat прошерстить в каталоге и во всех его подкаталогах. Я не понимаю как это сделать бесконечной глубины

Comment: могу миллионом вложенных циклов сделать, но не думаю что это вариант

Comment: `$ man find`, опционально `$ man xargs`

Comment: Описние в 3х словах - рекурсивный просмотр файлов

Comment: Никогда так не делайте, пока не убедитесь, что **все** файлы действительно текстовые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find {Your_Directory_No_Braces} -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs cat
```

Comment: Для удобного просмотра в консоли я бы предложил: `find ... | xargs more | less` (`more` в таком режиме сделает перед каждым файлом "шапку" с его именем, а `less` позволит просматривать весь вывод, перемещаясь по нему с возможностью поиска текста)

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./ -type f -exec cat {} \;
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat
grep -r . ./
ls -R | xargs cat
```

Выбырайте под конкретные нужды. Опишите какая цель.